# What is the correct punctuation in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Would someone please check and correct the following sentence for punctuation:

> A 9/11 widow psychiatrist, falls for a patient, who plans a similar attack to avenge his colleagues, annihilated in the false war that followed the 9/11.

Answer (score 1):

> A psychiatrist, widowed by the 9/11 attacks, falls for a patient who
>   plans a similar action to avenge his former colleagues, all of whom
>   were annihilated in the invasion of Iraq and the false war that followed.

That's how I would phrase it. I've added parenthetical commas at the beginning to make it read a bit easier, and so that there's no initial confusion about the subject of the piece. I would maybe refine your choice of the term "false war", because it was definitely a war, just a war of a highly questionable nature. Perhaps "unjustified" or something along those lines would be more appropriate? Using "false" seems a little blurry, in my opinion.